# Should I learn node.js before starting with meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, real-time

I'm coming from a java background, And I recently needed an app with realtime data and push. So i'm thinking of using meteor since it seems as an easier way to use node.js.

My question is do I need to learn node.js before starting with meteor ?
and is meteor suitable now for a production application (I know it haven't reached 1.0, but from your experiences what do you think)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor does not require knowing node.js in order to effectively build applications, as long as you stay within the boundaries of what Meteor abstracts away for you.

Meteor is very young, but "production-ready" depends on what exactly the application is. Would I write a real-time banking application with it right now? No. Is it ready for MVPs, demos, and straightforward consumer applications? Sure, as long as you understand its limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If it's not required, do you advice me to learn node.js? does it help me understand more, or go faster in meteor ?

Comment: You definitely can't hurt yourself by expanding your knowledge :). And it will accelerate Meteor development if you understand what's under the hood.

Comment: The Meteor way is quite different than the Node way- you won't understand Meteor any better by doing Express tutorials. Once you get to problems not solvable in Meteors solutions, that's the time to go deeper I think, unless you're simply curious and can learn two very different approaches at once